# Launching the android stopwatch from my app

Tags: android, stopwatch

I want to launch the stopwatch application that comes with android from my app but have no idea how to do this.
I do not want to create a stopwatch on my own since it needs to keep running when I close my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up until Android 4.1 (or maybe 4.2) AOSP Android did not have a stop watch in it, and there is no official SDK support for launching that part of the app. Stopwatches are likely installed by the user or the OEM on the majority of devices.